# How to reference the subsection number without the section number?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I would like to include just the subsection number of a subsection, without the section number.

I think this MWE summarizes what I am after. Is there an alternative to `\ref`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\label{subsec:Subsection}
I would like "\ref{subsec:Subsection}" to just return "2".
\end{document}
```

Comment: How should the reader distinguish if this ref points to section 2 or to subsection 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, ...?

Comment: Probably related: [ref to subsection number only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159299/134144)

Comment: @leandriis The same way we distinguish "on Friday": context. If you say in subsection 2, you mean of the current section. (I'm not defending the system, but I don't think the disambiguation problem is real.)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks for the explanation. So, one would still use `1.2` if the reference occures in section 3 but points to a subsection of section `1`?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, one supposes so. Or use "in subsection 2 of section 1" (clunky, but it gets the job done).

Comment: @hair-splitter This doesn't do what is asked for, since it will change the format of the subsection number in the heading, which is *not* desirable.

Comment: Dear all: I've taken the liberty of re-opening this posting, as the solutions provided to the earlier posting [ref to subsection number only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159299/5001) are all incompatible, to varying degrees, with `\autoref` of the `hyperref` package and `\cref` of the `cleveref` package. The answer given below does not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that's based on a technique that I learned from the book "The LaTeX Companion" (2nd ed.). It executes `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}` to reset the representation of the `subsection` counter, and it makes use of the low-level LaTeX command `\subsection@cntformat`, which governs how the `subsection` counter is displayed in subsection-level entries.

This solution is, by design, compatible with the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages and their cross-referencing macros, e.g., `\autoref`, `\cref`, and `\labelcref`.

*Addendum 2019/08/08*: I've added two lines to the code to generalize the solution to handle `subsubsection`-level headers as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % optional

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
       {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
       {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
    \def\subsection@cntformat{\thesection.\thesubsection\space} 
    \def\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection\space}
\makeatother

%Optional:
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections} 
\crefname{subsubsection}{subsubsection}{subsubsections} 

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}  % just for this example
The instructions \verb+\ref{sec:C2}+  and \verb+\labelcref{sec:C2}+ return ``\ref{sec:C2}'' and ``\labelcref{sec:C2}''.

The instructions \verb+\ref{sec:C11}+ and \verb+\labelcref{sec:C11}+ return ``\ref{sec:C11}'' and ``\labelcref{sec:C11}''.

\verb+\autoref+: \autoref{sec:C2} and \autoref{sec:C11}

And \verb+\cref+: \cref{sec:C2,sec:C11}

\addtocounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1} \label{sec:C11}
\subsection{Subsection 2} \label{sec:C2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A little side remark: The second upvote on this answer earned me the gold "cross-referencing" badge. Many thanks!!!